# iOS Path in Xamarin.Form to save data

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I want to save the data on a  csv file and I receive the Error that the Path doesn't exist. does anyone knows the correct Path ? I've searched in Internet and used the different paths but still doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your code.  File I/O in Xamarin Forms is well documented

Comment: Read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows) to know file handling in Xamarin.forms. There are information about [save path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

For getting the path to save files on iOS i used something like

```
            string photosPath = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments ) + "/Photos";
            IFileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.Current;
            IFolder rootFolder = fileSystem.LocalStorage;
            IFolder photosFolder = rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync( photosPath, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting ).Result;
            ImageRepository.ImagePath = photosPath;
```

Add this in iOS project.

Saved the path in another class instance to easily access it anywhere.

```
public class ImageRepository
    {
        public static string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
```

Use  `ImageRepository.ImagePath` as a path everywhere, where you want to save your file.